# jQuery not updating span even after successful AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I hava a PHP script which generates a PDF file (i'm using fpdf from www.fpdf.org). I'm calling the PHP from an html using AJAX $.post(.....). When submit button is clicked, the span shows 'please wait...'. The PDF is getting generated but still the span shows 'please wait...'. The span is not getting updated. Below is the code for AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#genByDt").submit(function()
{
    $("#msg").text('Please wait....').fadeIn(1000);

    var otherValidations = validate(document.genByDt);
    if(otherValidations == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {

        $.post("/pawn/fpdf/chittiCode/generateChitti.php",{ whichSubmitted:$('input[name = whichSubmitted]').val(), dateSelected:$('input[name = dateSelected]').val() }, function(data){

        var obj = $(data);              

        if($.trim($(obj,'body').text()) == 'success')
        {
            $("#msg").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){
                $(this).text('Bills generated successfully !!').fadeTo(900,1);
                $('input[name = dateSelected]').val('');
            });

        }
        else if($.trim($(obj,'body').text()) == 'zeroBills')
        {
            $("#msg").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){ 
                $(this).text('No bills for the selected date !!').fadeTo(900,1);
                $('input[name = dateSelected]').val('');
            });
        }

        });

        return false; //not to post the  form physically
    }
});

});
```

I know the problem is in the IFcondition. The PHP is returning a string but the $(data) is of type object[ I found this by using alert(obj); ]. Below is a part of the PHP:

```
if($success == 1)
{
echo "success";
}
else
{
echo "zeroBills";
}
```

Comment: @KristerAndersson - Please help man!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PHP is returning a string, then `data` will be a string and should be treated as such:

```
if (data === "success") {
   // your code here
} else if (data === "zeroBills") {
   // your code here
}
```

(You mentioned you found the type of `obj` by saying `alert(obj)`; what happens if you say `alert(data)`?)

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect? You took the string which was generated by your PHP script and converted it to a jQuery object using `$(data)`. After that it is no longer a string.

Second: You try to compare the content of element(s) with selector `obj` (which isn't a selector at all) beneath `body` with "success" without even adding it to the DOM.

Why didn't you just compare data with "success" in the first place??

```
if(data === "success")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need that as object? why not just using the string?

```
if(data === 'success')
{}
else if(data === 'zeroBills')
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically it's this: `$.trim($(obj,'body').text()`.

Why even assign a `obj` variable to `data`?

Try:

```
if(data == 'success')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the jQuery $.ajax function and in your PHP page :

echo 'Any message if success';

header('Error 404: Any error message'); (send an error code on purpose, i don't remmber the syntax)

success: function(html) { $("#message").html(html); },
error: function(x, e, t) { $("#message").html(t); } // "t" is the 'Any error code'